# Repairing Time Machine volume taking forever

Tags: time-machine, disk-utility

Over 18 hours and counting, currently in the "Checking multi-linked directories" phase, but it's been there all night long.

I see disk I/O, not a lot, but some. I assume its from the TM drive as the machine is nominally idle (as idle as these machines get, anyway).

What prompted me was that I kept glancing up and see it backing up. It was stuck doing a backup for a long time, so I simply stopped the backup, and tried again. Later, it was still taking forever and nothing happening. So I shut down TM, unmounted the drive, unplugged it, replugged it in. Then I decide to run Repair.

The basic question is if this repair time is "normal", or is the drive bad. I'm debating simply erasing the drive and starting over, but if the drive is bad, then it's not trustworthy.

Advice appreciated.

Comment: After an hour mine estimated just over a day. 18 hours later it's estimating 2 days, 1 hour. 12TB 2nd Gen. Drobo.

Comment: Need more information. How large is your drive (20GB? 500GB? 2TB? 20TB?)? How is it connected to your computer (Firewire? Network attached? USB? Thunderbolt?)

Answer (score 2):

The structure of a Time Machine disk is very complex.

Hundreds Gigabytes with hard links everywhere need a long time to check.

18 hours is not surprising.

Comment: So the recommendation is that I just stick with it and let it finish rather than wiping hastily in rage so I can install Lion? I mean, the bar IS moving, and so there is some "progress", but...

Comment: Now that you have warned us, the rest of us can start this process a few days BEFORE we intend to install Lion...